# how to install luarocks in rhel?

Tags: docker, lua, rhel, luarocks

I am trying to install luarocks in a docker image in the build stage

```
RUN yum makecache
RUN yum install -y luarocks
```

I see this error

```
 => [ 6/10] RUN yum makecache                                                                                                                                                                                       380.2s
 => ERROR [ 7/10] RUN yum install -y luarocks                                                                                                                                                                         4.7s
------
 > [ 7/10] RUN yum install -y luarocks:
#11 0.662 Loaded plugins: ovl, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
#11 0.693 
#11 0.693 This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
#11 0.693 
#11 4.450 No package luarocks available.
#11 4.632 Error: Nothing to do
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yum install -y luarocks]: exit code: 1
```

What is the problem?

How to install it using the binary?

Answer (score 0):

You don't state what image you're using, but LuaRocks is mostly likely in EPEL for this image, or is otherwise disabled.

Just a guess, but just preface your installation with:

```
yum -y install epel-release
```

If that doesn't work, something slightly more complicated is going on in the image you'll have to untangle with yum.